# How do we make an observation of a 4D spacetime trajectory if we, observers, have only access to a 3D world?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions

So far, I know that a trajectory in general relativity is a 4-vector, and a force-free particle follows a geodesic which is in 4D as well. My question is: how do we make an observation of such a trajectory if we, observers, have only access to a 3D world? Excuse my question if it turned out to be too naive!

Comment: The observers also have access to 4D since they also have 3 space + 1 time dimensions. The title of your question is very low quality by the way.

Comment: So, you plot the 4 vector of the trajectory by pivoting the space points in their place in space and with each point you say OK and here the particle will be at that position when this time t has elapsed  on my clock, right?

Comment: It may help to remember that our eyes only see in 2 dimensions, but we clearly learn about the 3d world using them!

Comment: We do the analogous thing when we study the motion of a cart on a 1-D track in PHY 101. We plot its motion on a position-vs-time graph---a (1+1)D=2D spacetime trajectory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don’t only have access to a 3D world. We can measure time with clocks and three dimensions of space with rulers. To measure a 4D worldline we just measure the location at many times, typically with respect to some physically implemented coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic assumption is not correct. Did Arthur Eddington have access to only a 3D world? Of course not - his experiment photographed a 4D geodesic that curved past the sun. He could not only measure 4D, he could see it with his eyes during an eclipse.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).